How many plane intersections to uniquely determine a surface
A brazilian math contest that ended yesterday posed the following problem (adapted and translated by me)
Let $S$ be some surface in $3$ dimensional space. Given that:

The intersection of $S$ with plane $z=1$ is a circle of equation $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$

The intersection of $S$ with plane $z=2$ is a circle of equation $x^{2}+y^{2}=2$

The intersection of $S$ with plane $x=1$ is an parabola with equation $z=ay^{2}+1$

The intersection of $S$ with plane $x=-1$ is an parabola with equation $z=ay^{2}+1$


5. $S$ is an quadratic surface
Find the equation that describes $S$.
Now, the problem itself is actually fairly easy (the answer is $x^{2}+y^{2}=z$). What im actually wondering is condition $5$. Im curious to know if removing the 5th condition adds any other (non quadratic) solutions, and if so, how would one find all such solutions.
My attempt
I haven't made a lot of progress. My working so far boils down to showing $a=1$.
Lemma 1: $a=1$.
Proof: Notice we can re-write facts 1 and 3 as:

If $z=2$, $x^{2}+y^{2}=2$ for all $x\leq \sqrt{2}$

If $x=1$, $z=ay^{2}+1$ for all $z \geq 1$.


Therefore, by taking $x=1$ and $z=2$, we get:
$2=ay^{2}+1$ and $1^{2} + y^{2}=2$. Therefore, $a+1=2\implies a=1$ $\blacksquare$
Now, my intuition is that:
a) There are no other polynomial solutions (regardless of the power)
b) There are infinitely many non polynomial solutions
But I have been unable to rigorously show a) [without handwaving terms away with
"something something can't vanish everywhere unless coeficient is 0"]
Any hints, progress or further reading recommendations are welcome!
Thanks in advance,
-Almeida

You could have solutions like $ x^2  + y^2 = z + (z-1)(z-2)(x-1)(x+1) f(x, y, z) $. $\quad$ It might not be a complete classification, since condition 3 and 4 could allow for much more leeway.

@CalvinLin thats... amazing

I feel dumb now ngl
